# ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using App Center to manage the build for iOS and the following is error I'm receiving in the build output:

```
    ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

I ran the build in Xcode and the archive was successful.

Any thoughts on why this fails in App Center ?

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. I ended up using the New Build System instead of the Legacy Build system. I initially had that option toggled on in the App Center Build for iOS.

Not sure why this was the fix I needed. Any thoughts on why this worked? I'm not well versed on the difference between the new and legacy build systems.

Answer (score 1):

got to build settings in the Project and the target and add to Library Search:

> $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
> $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)    $(inherited)

without quotes:

```
clean build folder -> run build
```

Comment: Thank you!. It works for react native projects also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the Facebook teams haven't fixed it, the solution is this:

- Open Xcode and bring the `Build Settings`
- Bring the `Search Paths` and then double click on `Library search paths` to modify it
- Add `${inherited}` to the first of the list [*It's important to be the first*]
- Go back to the terminal and navigate to the `ios` folder
- Delete the build folder by this command `rm -rf build/`
- Try to run the project (No difference between the CLI of Xcode)